# LTC-3588: how to do vibration energy harvesting?

Tags: piezo, energy-harvesting

I am trying to collect energy by using an [LTC3588](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/35881fc.pdf) and some piezo elements.

The voltage meter shows from -200mV to 200mV depending on how much / how strong I touch the piezo. I have set the LTC to 3.6V output and attached a 47µF, 6V capacitor. I don't see it getting "filled" no matter how long I rattle. What am I missing?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You are going to have to include a more detailed circuit diagram.  The block diagram isn't sufficient.  You may also need to include photos of your circuit.

Comment: Did you connected the piezo to the Pins PZ1 and PZ2 as shown in the datasheet? https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/35881fc.pdf

Comment: The LTC3588 has a Vin undervoltage lockout set at several volts depending on the set output voltage. So if the piezo is only giving you +/-200mV, the lockout is active.

Comment: @JRE can't edit the question post. but there is not much to it: connected the piezo to PZ1/PZ2 and the capacitor to GND/VCC.

Comment: @HansmitmFlammenwerfer: yes

Comment: @DønerM.:  You should be able to edit the question.

Comment: @Hyp: oh, I must have missed that. the datasheet says 14-20v input range. so the LTC3588 is not the right thing to use it seems

Comment: @DønerM.: Did you build the circuit as shown in the datasheet?

Comment: ... but I wonder what piezo elements produce THAT much voltage anyway. they must the huge. what sense makes the LTC3588 then anyway. know of a board that would be capable to work with such low voltage input?

Comment: The LTC3588 accepts up to 18V input, but it does not require it.  Piezos generate actually rather high voltage peaks when flexed, even small ones.  Note that they need to be **bent**, not just waved around in the air.

Comment: A voltmeter won't show you what the piezo is doing.  You need an oscilloscope to catch the peaks.

Comment: @JRE I have added an image. and I didn't know that the piezo needs to be bend, because they are made for rather high frequencies. I don't think they are made for tough bending. is there a similar circuit that works with such low input voltages?

Comment: The lower limit is that there's about a 400mV drop across the rectifier in the LTC3588.  Your piezo will have to generate more voltage than that.  It makes quite a difference that you are using a module rather than the IC in a circuit you built yourself.

Comment: @JRE: I do have the IC here as well, but a) they are SO tiny, I am not sure how to solder this and b) I wouldn't know what to add to get it working with my piezos or even lower voltages (20mV). I know the datasheet but my knwloedge of circuit builds are very limited and I cannot find any real examples. someone MUST have done this already?!

Comment: You will need to look at the voltage on the storage capacitor of the module rather than the output voltage.  The output is shutoff until the internal capacitor is sufficiently charged.

Answer (score 0):

To charge the capacitor requires that:

- The voltage from the piezo is sufficiently high for long enough to power on the LTC3588 (i.e. above its minimum Vin)
- The power generated by the piezo exceeds the power consumption of the LTC3588 itself (power is the combination of current and voltage, which for piezo elements is often very low, not least because their impedance is very high)
- The average of the remaining power level (assuming there is any), exceeds the leakage through the LTC3588 (when not active) and the electrolytic capacitor.

I would guess that you are failing on at least point 1 and 3, as whilst the LTC3588 is a nano-power converter, the piezo element you are using appears much smaller than the elements in the example circuits in the datasheet.